# Joomla Mailchimp - send newsletter after submit new article. Automatic

Tags: joomla, newsletter

I am facing a little problem. I integrated Mailchimp into Joomla 3 (Joomlamailer) and I need to automatically inform my subscribers, when a new article is posted.

I tried to find solutions without success. Any ideas?

Comment: you need to create a joomla plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Create a cron job that will check for articles that were created in the past 24 hours, and that will use the MailChimp API to send a notification to your subscribers.